# Magento 1.9 Get customer data an products in Observer on invoice save on php 7.1

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, save

I want to get on event sales_order_invoice_save_after customer data / products to put on external billing sistem:

```
    public function factura(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
    $custName    = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
    $orderPrice  = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $orderId     = $order->getId();
   foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );
    }
    $arrOrder = array(
        'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
        'store'         => 'magento',
        'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
        'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
        'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
        'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
        'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
        'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
        'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
        'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),
        'items'        => $items,
    );

    Mage::print_a($arrOrder);
    die();
}
```

all i recive is:

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getIncrementId() on null in /home/anystore/app/code/community/GSMBoutique/Fgoro/Model/Observer.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): GSMBoutique_Fgoro_Model_Observer->factura(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#1 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(GSMBoutique_Fgoro_Model_Observer), 'factura', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/anystore/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_inv...', Array)
#3 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_inv...', Array)
#4 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(996): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#5 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->_afterSave()
#6 /home/anystore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract in /home/anystore/app/code/community/GSMBoutique/Fgoro/Model/Observer.php on line 8
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if your question not solve.

Comment: @GSM Boutique can you let me know what will be the issue you are still facing ?

Comment: Is it working for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man (in M1) you are capturing invoice event and getting order from it :P

If you want to get order do the following:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$invoice = $event->getInvoice();
$orderData = $invoice->getOrder();
$orderId = $orderData->getId();
// If you want more information for order which is not present in $orderData load order object
$order = Mage::getModel ('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

Now get what you want from $order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); //For get order details
 $order_id = $order->getIncrementId(); //Get order id
 $product_ids = [];
 $product_name = []
 foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product_ids[]  = $item->getProductId(); //product id
    $product_name[] = $item->getName(); // product name
 }
 $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // shipping address
 $customer = $order->getCustomerId(); // For get customer id
}
```